# best way to create a timer for a game

Tags: objective-c, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I have a time limiter for a game I am doing, what I am doing right now is using an initial value and deducting one value per frame update. here is the code :

```
- (void) gameTime {
    fullTime = fullTime - 1;
    NSLog(@"%i", fullTime);
    float xScale = 10 * fullTime / 4000;
    //_game.timerGraphic.scaleX = 10;
    //[_game.timerGraphic setScaleX:10];
    [_game.timerGraphic setScaleX:xScale];    
}
```

now the problem is that `timerGraphic` is a `CCSprite`, and when I update the `ScaleX` it doesnt work unless its a absolute value, is there anyway i can make this smoother and resize the "timer" in a smoother way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this sort of approach is that is makes the timer in your app dependent on the frame rate. Cocos2D has some built in mechanisms for dealing with these sorts of issues. In particular, the idea is that each time you load a new frame, you update animation values based on the amount of time *elapsed* between the previous and current frame. Look at the "Making Things Move" section in [this Cocos2D tutorial](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3alesson_2._your_first_game). It explains how to schedule a selector (i.e., create a timer to fire the `-nextFrame:` method). This method get passed a `dt` (delta time) argument that can be used for creating smooth animations.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply, but now I found out the issue, you see when you want to scale up a thing using float apparently you should use `f` at the end of it like `1.5f`, BUT in my example thats not happening, its doing `1.5` instead!!! can you tell me how I can do that?

Comment: I don't think that's your issue here. Putting `f` at the end of a decimal-valued literal just means that you want that number to explicitly be a `float` instead of a `double` (the default in objective-c for decimal literals). What is true is that where you have `fullTime / 4000` is performing integer division instead of floating point division. You can fix that by writing `(float)10.0 * fullTime / 4000.0`. Still, though, your animation code is relying on the frame rate which is never going to be as smooth as possible.

Comment: thanks alot, your code actually works, I know the animation wont be, for other stuff I have used `runAction` but I just cant get my head around how I would do this with runAction, and the current code has a semi smooth animation to it. one last question, the ScaleX, is there anyway to resize/setScaleX from one side of the sprite rather than both sides ? (the current code expands the image from both sides )

Comment: `_game.timerGraphic.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0.5f)` to scale only from the right or `_game.timerGraphic.anchorPoint = ccp(1,0.5f)` to scale only from the left. The anchorPoint property of a `CCNode` defines the point around which all tranformations take place.